# Oracle dbms_scheduler: Can I create a job that will not overlap with itself?

Tags: oracle, jobs

How can I ensure that a dbms_scheduler job will never have more than one instance running?

For example, if I have a job that is scheduled to run once a minute, but it actually runs for three minutes, I don't want a second and third instance of the job to start and run concurrently.

*(note) I previously asked [this question](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/109441/oracle-jobs-can-i-create-a-job-that-will-not-overlap-with-itself) specifying that either dbms_scheduler or dbms_jobs solutions were acceptable.  I have since learned that dbms_jobs does not work well on RAC, hence this dbms_scheduler-specific question. (end note)*

Comment: Can you schedule the job using a bash script?

Comment: Query dba_scheduler_jobs_running to see if the job is already running, and exit if it is

Answer (score 2):

yes, you can, this in fact is default behaviour. See [Database Administrator’s Guide chapter 29 Scheduling Jobs with Oracle Scheduler](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ADMIN/scheduse.htm#ADMIN-GUID-CDAC9D52-61F2-484B-BF5E-874EDEAE2CD2)

> Immediately after a job starts, the repeat_interval is evaluated to
>   determine the next scheduled execution time of the job. While this
>   might arrive while the job is still running, a new instance of the job
>   does not start until the current one completes.

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't this accomplish the same thing that @Justin Cave did in the other thread?

```
BEGIN
DBMS_SCHEDULER.CREATE_JOB 
(
   job_name             => 'hr.employees_jobs',
   job_type             => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
   job_action           => 'BEGIN proc_that_takes_3_minutes; END;',
   start_date           => systimestamp,  
   repeat_interval      => 'FREQ=MINUTELY;INTERVAL=1',
   enabled              =>  TRUE,
   comments             => 'Gather table stats on hr.employees'
) ;
END ;
/
```

Comment: by my understanding, dbms_job reschedules at the end of each job run, whereas dbms_scheduler starts at the scheduled time even if another job is running.